# Program to Determine What Type of Mathematical Term a String Is

Tags: java, int, try-catch

I'm using a scanner class to allow the user input a string, and the program is to then determine whether the string is a.) just a number b.) just a variable c.) a coefficient times a variable d.) a variable to a power or d.) a coefficient times a variable to a power. For example, if the user inputs "3", the program determines it's case a; if the user inputs "x^43", the computer determines it's case d.

Honestly, I have no idea where to go on this one. I attempted to make a try-catch block to see if the sting could be converted to a number, but that only hits case a. I'm not sure how I can make a concise code that can check the string to find a pattern in order to determine which case it is. Can someone please steer me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Shubhang

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: Adding on to the response from @ajb - you can either parse the string entered by the user character-by-character and use a bunch of complicated logic, or you can leverage RegEx (or Regular Expression) for pattern-matching.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use a real parser for the math expressions. You can for example use my [Symja](https://bitbucket.org/axelclk/symja_android_library/wiki/Home) project. In the [Calculus example](https://bitbucket.org/axelclk/symja_android_library/wiki/examples/Calculus) you see the basic usage. After evaluation, you can call these methods to detect the type of the `result` expression.

```
result.isNumber()
result.isSymbol()
result.isTimes()
result.isPower()
```

If the expression is a `Times()` or `Power()` expression, you can cast it to an [AST expression](https://bitbucket.org/axelclk/symja_android_library/wiki/doc/ClassHierarchy.wiki) and detect further properties.